# Ubuntu 17.10 on Dell XPS 15 9560

Tags: ubuntu, nvidia-geforce, dell-xps

I am trying to get Ubuntu 17.10 set up on my laptop.  Since my SSD is running Windows 10, I can't repartition that, so I'm doing Ubuntu on a USB flash drive.  I've installed Ubuntu on the flash drive and it boots, but after that things go haywire.  I had to add **nomodeset** to the kernel line, and the laptop always freezes when I try to go to tty1 (which I believe is where gdm3 runs).  So far I have blacklisted the nouveau drivers and installed Nvidia 390.42 for GeForce 1050 graphics card.  That went well, but it didn't fix  the freezing issue.  I also disabled Wayland because that I've learned doesn't play nice with Nvidia.

I've had to force shut off my laptop so many times I can't even count anymore.  Does anyone know what could be causing the freezing and how I can fix it?

Comment: did u find a solution @vcapra1 ?

Comment: Yeah.  What I did was a fresh install, and instead of using apt-get upgrade, I used the GUI updater when it prompted me shortly after the first startup.  Idk if this is what did it, but it's the only thing I can think of that I did differently.  I'm sorry I couldn't be more helpful, but I honestly have no idea why it worked.  Let me know if you have any other questions

Comment: no, that was very helpful, thank you so much!